# no eksctl-managed CloudFormation stacks found > Error: loading VPC spec for cluster,

Tags: kubectl, amazon-eks, eksctl

I have created EKS cluster manually. Now when I am trying to create a nodegroup for Windows by following this link [launch-windows-workers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-windows-workers.html)

I am getting this below error:-

> 2021-09-03 06:28:02 [!]  no eksctl-managed CloudFormation stacks found for "testEnv-cluster", will attempt to create nodegroup(s) on non
> eksctl-managed cluster Error: loading VPC spec for cluster
> "testEnv-cluster": VPC configuration required for creating nodegroups
> on clusters not owned by eksctl: vpc.subnets, vpc.id, vpc.securityGroup

1. How do I own this cluster for eksctl which was earlier manually created by eks and then following process was accomplished by kubectl ?
2. How do I create node-group for Windows instance under my cluster ?
3. How to create the cloudformation stack for the Windows NodeGroup ?

any help

Answer (score 1):

> How do I own this cluster for eksctl which was earlier manually created by eks and then following process was accomplished by kubectl ?

You can create node group even in a cluster not created by `eksctl`. However, since `eksctl` can't fetch cluster info from CloudFormation, you need to manually input network configuration in `ClusterConfig`.

Here's an example from the [official document](https://eksctl.io/usage/unowned-clusters/) See this link for further detail.

```
vpc:
  id: "vpc-12345"
  securityGroup: "sg-12345"    # this is the ControlPlaneSecurityGroup
  subnets:
    private:
      private1:
          id: "subnet-12345"
      private2:
          id: "subnet-67890"
    public:
      public1:
          id: "subnet-12345"
      public2:
          id: "subnet-67890"
```

> How do I create node-group for Windows instance under my cluster ?
> How to create the cloudformation stack for the Windows NodeGroup ?

You can create managed or self-managed node group using `eksctl` by adding node groups with `amiFamily: WindowsServer2019FullContainer` or other Windows AMIs. `eksctl` will automatically created a Cloudformation stack for each node group.

Here's an example from the [official document](https://eksctl.io/usage/windows-worker-nodes/)

```
managedNodeGroups:
  - name: windows-managed-ng
    amiFamily: WindowsServer2019FullContainer
    minSize: 2
    maxSize: 3
```